# Bug in PHP time conversion?

Tags: php, timezone

```
TimeZoneNameFrom = 'PST';
TimeZoneNameTo = 'Europe/Amsterdam';
TimeStr = '2019-3-20 23:59:00';

$convertedTime = date_create($TimeStr, new DateTimeZone($TimeZoneNameFrom))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($TimeZoneNameTo))->format("j F H.i");
```

Why does this give

> 21 March 08.59 CET

instead of the correct

> 21 March 07.59 CET

?

Comment: I check with time.is website there is 9 hours difference between PST and Amsterdam time zone, what you get is correct.

Comment: I checked it too on https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/, but on March 21st, the time difference is actually 8 hours, not 9.

Comment: Currently Day time saving is in effect, countries using PST now using PDT, the difference between PDT and Amsterdam is 8 hours. https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?pl=1&lid=8,2759794,208&h=208

Comment: Changing PST into PDT still gives exactly the same result (9 hours) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: Daylight Saving Time - Not a fan. I cannot explain why "PDT" also gives the wrong result. But instead of having to know what time of year it is and when the clocks change, suggest putting the tz from and tz to into the same "unit of measure" and let the computer figure it out. Use "America/Los_Angeles" for tz from and you should see the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll do that then.